# sql server query to find name of the SSIS Package the Agent is running

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to find the name of SSIS package the agent job step is running. I tried below query to get the command. But it shows the entire command along with path and name. I need only package name. For Example, 'ABCDEFG.dtsx' from below result.

USE MSDB
GO
SELECT Command FROM sysjobsteps Where subsystem = 'SSIS'
GO

Result: /FILE "\"L:\Packages\ABCDEFG.dtsx\"" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E

Is there a way to get only package name from above result. Appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use string processing to extract the name. Like look for the first occurence of the string ".dtsx" in the results. This would give the index. Do a substring on the result from beginning till that index. Then find last occurence of "\" in the substring. it will again give the position of "\" within the string. Now you can do a substring for the rest of the string.

Suppose @result variable contains the output of the query.

```
DECLARE @stringIndex INT
DECLARE @remainingString VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @stringIndex = CHARINDEX('.dtsx', @result)
SELECT @remainingString = SUBSTRING(@result, 1, @stringIndex)
SELECT @remainingString = REVERSE(@remainingString)
SELECT @stringIndex = CHARINDEX('/', @remainingString)
SELECT @remainingString = SUBSTRING(@remainingString, 1, @stringIndex)
SELECT @remainingString = REVERSE(@remainingString)
```

The above query should work for you. Since SQL Server doesn't have something like last index I have used `REVERSE` as substitute.